# Copy a screenshot of an area to clipboard

Tags: discussion, duplicates

No, I don't want to copy the screenshot of an area to the clipboard. But these users do:

1. [How to get back previous screenshot functionality on 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1404753/158442)
2. [Screenshot selection in 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1407422/158442)
3. ["Copy a screenshot area to clipboard" isn't available on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1408270/158442)

(and maybe others, but these were the most recently active)

Can we merge the useful answers of these into one post?

Comment: To get the discussion going there is this entry in the Moderator Cheat Sheet concerning merging: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet#119518

Comment: I don't agree with merging all these questions. As stated in the link that andrew.46 shared about when two questions should be merged:  *When the exact same question gets asked twice and the answers on both are worth preserving, you should merge one into the other. You should only merge if the answers on the question-to-be-merged make perfect sense on the target question.* I think that the first and the second questions do not ask for exactly the same thing, so merging would not be appropriate for them. The second and third seem OK for merging though.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog note the very first sentence of the second question is their goal, which is shared by all three users here: to get 'the "old" functionality of taking screenshots of area selections and pasting them into clipboard', and the last sentence is the gripe with the current feature set that both the first and second user have: extra clicks. The second user just hit up on one possible solution and tried to make that work, but Stack Exchange *always* has had a tradition of looking at the underlying need and not just the XY problem at hand.

Comment: I am wondering in the interests of getting some resolution we might be better to simply make the second question the *canonical* question and mark 1 and 3 as Duplicates? Not a great measure of usefulness perhaps but I see the view counts of these questions as: 1. 398 views 2. 3k views 3. 221 views.

Comment: @andrew.46 yes, that's still much better than the current situation

Answer (score 1):

There has not been *huge* discussion of this issue but it has been a good time to visit the idea of merging. The following quote from the [Moderator Cheat Sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet) goes to the crux of the issue when [merging questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet#119518):

> **When should I merge questions, as opposed to just closing as a duplicate?**
>
> When the *exact* same question gets asked twice and the answers on both are worth preserving, you should merge one into the other. You should only merge if the answers on the question-to-be-merged make perfect sense on the target question.

There certainly should *not* be all three question of these questions active on Ask Ubuntu, there is far too much overlap and thus dilution of community effort and the ability to find a canonical, accepted answer on AU.

But neither is there the '*exact* same question' and answers that 'make perfect sense on the target question' as mentioned on the Moderator Cheat Sheet. I note as well the following statement on the Cheat Sheet:

> **I am not sure if I should vote to close or merge?**
>
> Merging should be much more unusual - it's in the mod menu. The answers must make sense on the target question - hence closing as duplicate first. If in doubt, ask.

And so in the presence of some variation of opinion and some doubt about the correct course of action the better course, I believe, (and @muru has agreed that this is at least better than the current situation) is to close questions 1 and 3 as Duplicates of question 2.

It is a bit of a 'line ball' call but the mechanisms are available here on meta or an Ask Ubuntu (Re-edit / Reopen Votes etc) to disagree :)